# ¿Cómo hacer una división decimal de un número mayor a 10^308 en Python?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Intento hacer esta división como parte de un algoritmo de cambio de bases numéricas y me da error de desbordamiento.

```
    Python 3.4.0a2 (v3.4.0a2:9265a2168e2c+, Sep  8 2013, 19:41:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890/97
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890/97
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
>>>
```

Comment: Simplemente como recomendación que nada tiene que ver con la pregunta en si y que ya a contestado @toledano correctamente, deberias actualizar Python, estas usando  la segunda alpha de la versión 3.4, no se trata de una versíon final y puedes encontrar bugs ya solventados. El último lanzamiento de la 3.4 es la versión [Python 3.4.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-346/). También puedes pasarte a la 3.6.0 pero si por compatibilidad necesitas la 3.4 deberias no usar una alpha si es posible. Saludos.

Comment: En Ubuntu tengo esta versión: Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23). y también me sirvió el código. En caso de seguir tu recomendación de actualizar ¿Como lo haría? no tengo problemas en cambiar la versión, de hecho me gustaría eliminar la versión 2.7 que trae por defecto. En el caso del IDLE de Python ¿viene con una versión especifica o el ejecuta la mas actual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el módulo `decimal` que permite manejar números de cualquier magnitud, sin las limitaciones de tu hardware.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890)/decimal.Decimal(97)
>>> d
Decimal('1.272750402189130710322005854537355224628993254421662212040104365533907343769885579737813300241822567E+677')
>>> print(d)
1.272750402189130710322005854537355224628993254421662212040104365533907343769885579737813300241822567E+677
```

Consulta la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Comment: Gracias @toledano, tambien me sirvio en esta version: Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23), en Ubuntu 16.04